# I have a TypeError in Python script

Tags: python

I have write this short code:

```
from cv2 import cv2

img = cv2.imread("1.png")

print("Высота:"+str(img.shape[0]))
print("Ширина:" + str(img.shape[1]))
print("Количество каналов:" + str(img.shape[2]))

for x in img.shape[0]:
    for y in img.shape[1]:
        if img[x, y] == (255, 255, 255):
            img[x, y] = (0, 0, 0)

cv2.imwrite("result.png", img)
```

And I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Projects\Captcha Decrypt\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    for x in img.shape[0]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can you solve this problem?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it? `img.shape[0]` is an integer not an iterable (list, dict, etc.)

Comment: Regarding the print you wrote just before, you can see that `img.shape[0]` is an INT, how do you want ot iterate on it ? From 0 to that value ? use a `range` for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all: you are trying to iterate over a number, which is not possible, you can only iterate over objects having implemented the `__iter__` or `__next__` method. If `img.shape[0]` is for example 100, and you want to iterate a hundred times, you should use a `range` instead. That's basically a list of numbers, over which you can then iterate. Try this one:

```py
from cv2 import cv2

img = cv2.imread("1.png")

print("Высота:" + str(img.shape[0]))
print("Ширина:" + str(img.shape[1]))
print("Количество каналов:" + str(img.shape[2]))

for x in range(img.shape[0]):
    for y in range(img.shape[1]):
        if img[x, y] == (255, 255, 255):
            img[x, y] = (0, 0, 0)

cv2.imwrite("result.png", img)
```

Comment: @РостиславРоманец No need to add a comment `Thanks. It is working`, instead, rather accept and optionally upvote my answer ! ;)